# What is difference between ATMEGA32 and ATMEGA328?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, atmega32u4

I'm new in electronics. Just playing with Arduino boards.I just wanted to program ATMEGA328 micro-controller and use it without Arduino for compact design for my personal hobby project. I found there are ATMEGA32 and ATMEGA328 micro controllers in my local store. So, I wanted to know can I use ATMEGA32 instead of ATMEGA328 ? Which one is latest and whats are benefits. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ATMega32 looks to be essentially the "big brother" of the ATMega328.  Just the same chip internally, but with more IO pins. I don't know about register / code compatibility, or Arduino core API support, having never used one.

Comment: you can't put ATmega32 into the DIP socket on Uno. the DIP version has a different size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell for sure, but from a cursory look at the datasheets, the
ATmega32 *looks* older:

- 16 MHz maximum frequency v.s. 20 MHz for the ATmega328
- 4.5 V minimum supply voltage v.s; 1.8 V for the ATmega328
- only one PWN channel per 8-bit timer

From an Arduino-programming point of view, I would prefer the 328, as it
would allow you to prototype your code on an Uno, and then move it to
the bare MCU, knowing it would work identically. The ATmega32 would be
worth consideration if you need more IO than the Uno can provide.

Answer (score 3):

I can't post comments.
One difference is that the ATmega32 has **JTAG**; ATmega328P has not.

Comment: +1 It's not terribly complete, but it seems okay to post an answer.  It's answer type material at least.  And something not pointed out by others.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this you'd need to study the according data sheets:

[ATmega32](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega32)
[ATmega32u4](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega32u4)
[ATmega328](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega328)
[ATmega328P](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega328P)
[ATmega328PB](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega328PB)

Despite a similar name, the chips are quite different.
32u4 for examle has USB built in.
328PB has more 16-bit Timer/Counters.
... and many more differences.

They only differ on the hardware features and can be programmed in more or less the same way. It is up to you to choose which one you want to use.

Comment: The only nearly identical ones are 328 and 328P. If you don't care about the "picopower" feature you just have to know they have different signatures. To _easiest_ move from an arduino (UNO or NANO) to a standalone controller, **atmega328p** is your choice.